# How to find strings within a text file in JAVA

Tags: java, string, file, object, io

I'd like to just see an example with some explanation. 
What string functions do I use to compare the objects and does it compare each character or the actual word without any additional letters to it?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want someone to do your homework

Comment: I'd like a trillion dollars, but without some effort, it's not going to happen.  Try and break down your question into manageable chunks. There are a number of ways you might find a string within a `String`, you could do it manually (`String#contains`) or use `RegularExpression` to find patterns of text, it would depend on the context of what you're trying to find.  Read a file generally isn't that hard and there are any number of possible examples demonstrating how that can be done.

Comment: @Kon I'm currently not in any JAVA courses. Only C. I just wanted to learn JAVA on my own but I'm unfamiliar with objects.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry if I'm being too vague I guess this was more for concept understanding of objects when comparing their values together versus primitive data types.

Comment: The one thing to watch out for is that if you're comparing Strings in Java, never use `==` and instead use `.equals()`.

Comment: @SeniorPepe With objects, typically you can call a method to do your comparisons. For `String` objects that is done with `String.equals("the string you are checking against")` This method returns a `boolean`. You'll find this becomes more intuitive over time.

Comment: @DM methods are used to compare objects? Do these methods have return values for any important indication?

Comment: @SeniorPepe `.equals` will just return a boolean indicating whether it was equal.

Comment: @SeniorPepe You may also find `String.contains("substring you are searching for")` to be useful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing something very similar to this question for a project awhile ago.  There are numerous ways to do this in Java, but I used the Scanner class and the File class.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);      //Just a normal scanner

    System.out.println("Please enter in the pathname to the file you want to view.");
    String pathname = input.nextLine();          //Pathname to text file
    File book = new File(pathname);              //Creating a new file using the pathname

    if(book.canRead() == false)                  //If Java cant read the file, this will pop up
    {
        System.out.println("Your file cannot be read");
    }
    else if(book.canRead() == true)              //If Java can read the file, then this asks for the word to search for
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter in the word you wish to search for.");
        wordToSearchFor = input.nextLine();

        wordCounter(book);                        //Calls the method
  }

  System.out.println(wordToSearchFor.toLowerCase() + " appeared " + numOfOccurrences + " times in " + pathname);

}
```

This is the main method where you use the File class to create a file based off  of a pathname that you give it EX - C:\Users\alex\Downloads\mobydick.txt
I then check to see if you can read the file, and if you can, then I call a method to analyze the book itself

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextReader
{
    private static int numOfOccurrences;         //Counter to keep track of the number of occurances
    private static String wordToSearchFor;       //String field so both methods can access it

    /*
    * This method takes in the file of the book so the scanner can look at it
    * and then does all of the calculating to see if the desired word appears,
    * and how many times it does appear if it does appear
    */

    public static void wordCounter(File bookInput)
    {
        try                                         
        {                                               
            Scanner bookAnalyzer = new Scanner(bookInput);     //Scanner for the book

            while(bookAnalyzer.hasNext())                      //While the scanner has something to look at next
            {
                String wordInLine = bookAnalyzer.next();        //Create a string for the next word

                wordInLine = wordInLine.toLowerCase();          //Make it lowercase
                String wordToSearchForLowerCase = wordToSearchFor.toLowerCase();
                String wordToSearchForLowerCasePeriod = wordToSearchForLowerCase + ".";

                if(wordInLine.indexOf(wordToSearchForLowerCase) != -1 && wordInLine.length() == wordToSearchFor.length())
                {
                    numOfOccurrences++;
                }
                else if(wordInLine.indexOf(wordToSearchForLowerCasePeriod) != -1 && wordInLine.length() == wordToSearchForLowerCasePeriod.length())
                {
                    numOfOccurrences++;
                }
            }
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException e)               //Self explanitory
        {
            System.out.println("The error is FileNotFoundException - " + e);
            System.out.println("This should be impossible to get to because error checking is done before this step.");
        }
    }
```

Scanners in Java can be take a File object to analyze, which is the fist thing I do in this method.  I then use a while loop and ask the Scanner if there is a word that follows the current word.  As long as there is a word, this will continue to run.  I then create a String of the current word that the scanner is on to use as a reference to compare against.  I then use a method that comes with the String class to make everything lowercase because uppercase and lowercase letters matter.

The first if statement in this method checks if the current word that the scanner has matches what you are searching for using the indexOf method from the String class, which takes some string and looks to see if it exists in another string.  The if statement comparison also makes sure that the desired word length is the same as the word length in the book in case you are looking up "the" and it doesnt mark "then" as a word since it contains "the".  The second if statement does the same thing, just with your desired word with a period at the end.  If you wanted to go the extra mile, you could also check for exclamation points, question marks, commas, and so forth, but I decided to just check for periods.

Every time one of these if statements is correct, I increment a variable by one, and after the scanner runs out of words to search for, I print out the total number of times that certain word appears in a text file.